# Should one act upon comments that the content filter should have blocked and if yes, in what way?

Tags: discussion

The comment content filter is supposed to prevent certain kinds of text from being entered. One example is the '+1' prefix for indicating that one upvoted a question or an answer, usually followed by context unrelated to the question and answer, like lauding the author.

A somewhat easy way to circumvent the filter is to replace an offending character with a substitute rendered as a similar glyph. In the example given that could be `＋` (U+FF0B) which passes the content filter.

In fact, [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1074152/number-of-comments-starting-with--uff0b-instead-of) shows that this particular choice has been employed in ~320k comments.

What should we do about it, if anything at all?

Obviously, manual inspection and flagging is out of the question. I can think of these options:

- do nothing
- document it somewhere (else than in this question)
- notify somebody (whom?)
- create / add to a database of substitutions
- submit a query to retire these comments (if that is possible at all)

PS: This is not about discussing whether the input filters are reasonable.

**Update**

The referenced SEDE query was incorrect (reason: collation not being accounted for in character comparison). Actually there are only 84 instances of `＋` ( U+FF0B ). The query has been updated.

Comment: People will ALWAYS be able to bypass filters. If nothing else, people will start writing it out instead..... The filter is just there to prevent the easiest of easy cases. It won't be useful to hunt down. Anyway, the "-1" and "+1" filters are mainly to stop people from explaining their votes... it's not a rule. It's to prevent people from explaining something irrelevant.

Comment: Certainly don't go start flagging stuff en-mass that aren't doing harm just because they cheated around a filter. Do nothing imo.

Comment: If you are ruling out manual flagging, then do nothing, I guess. Otherwise, if you see a comment that falls under any of the various flag descriptions (e.g. harassment, unfriendly, no longer needed), flag it as such, whether it's "causing harm" or not. Such comments are noise and we don't want noise on the site.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect quite a lot of people disagree with your postscript. The issues are not separable, and you cannot realistically expect to discuss "whether we should flag [thing X]" without also discussing "whether [thing X] is actually harmful." There is no meaningful distinction between those two issues.

Comment: Your SEDE query is flawed. It also counts the regular plus sign. (312853 of them.) [There are only 84](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1074184/number-of-comments-starting-with--uff0b-instead-of) using the U+FF0B.

Comment: @Kevin I think they are separable indeed. It's the difference between site policy and enforcement of site policy. I also pointed out that this Q is about [thing X]s for which flagging is impractical.

Comment: @Ivar You are right ! The [first char distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1074203/comments-first-char-distribution) indicates 2 (84) occurrences of U+FF0B on SO (SO Meta). Comparing characters instead of unicode code points involves collation rules that appear to pack '+' (U+002B) with '＋' (U+FF0B) into the same bin and thus yielding false results.

Comment: I disagree. "Should we have [policy X]" is not meaningfully distinct from "Should we enforce [policy X]." The unenforced policy is no policy at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the content itself.  Some of the content filters are there just to help guide people in the right direction.  Others are there to protect users from themselves (or from the repercussion to their post).  And others are there to prevent spam, abuse, or other offensive content.

If it falls into one of the first 2 (guiding users or protecting them from themselves), then the users chose to circumvent the content filter knowingly in order to post. There is absolutely no reason to do anything about it.  The user knows what they posted was not allowed and the chose to do it anyway.  Mass flagging is only going to add burden to the moderator workload.

Another consideration is whether the content is actually valuable.  This is mostly for comments.  If a comment is unnecessary, adds noise to the post, and/or offers no long term value to the site, then flag away.  We don't need comments that don't have anything meaningful to say.

But if someone is finding a workaround to getting spam, hate speech, or other offensive content posted, then you need to flag.  For a couple of posts (comments, questions, or answers), flagging each post manually will do.  But if there is a large number or a pattern by a single user, then a manual flag with a link to the user and/or links to the offending posts would probably be better.

Specifically, since you mentioned the +1 / -1 comment prohibition, this falls into the first or second items (guiding users or protecting them from themselves).  So you are fine to ignore it.